# Turn xact_Abort on for specific applications or user

Tags: sql-server-2012, connectivity

We have a 3rd party application that requires xact_abort to be turned on, however we have other applications that require it to be turned off.

The service that requires it turned on always logs in with the same username and has its own application name.

Is there a way that we can configure the connection string to ignore the default setting and turn xact_abort on for it's connection? We don't have access to the source code of the application so are unable to add a command to set it to on.

The server is SQL 2012 Enterprise